# WP7 how to implement a better pivot control?

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot, swipe

I'm using pivot control to display a large number of images (about 300). I thought of just using 3 pivot item, and when user swipes, change either pivot item or update item source. But I don't know how to do this efficiently ?

Or is there a way of using gesture and stimulating swipe effect as the pivot does ? Something like transition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use normal Image Control with gesture Manipulation events to swipe left to right and right to left for previous/next photos.

Please find the code below.

```
XAML Code 

  <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="0">        
     <Image Margin="0" x:Name="ImagePanel"  Source="{Binding SelectedPhoto.PhotoURL}" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
  </Grid>

C# code 
  public SlideShow()
     {
  // Tag ManipulationCompleted event for the current page in the constructor. 
    ManipulationCompleted += new EventHandler<ManipulationCompletedEventArgs>(SlideShow_ManipulationCompleted);
     }

    // ManipulationCompleted event. Update the Previous/next photo based on the swipe direction. 
 void SlideShow_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var manipEndPoint = e.TotalManipulation.Translation;
            const int threshold = 100;

            if ((manipEndPoint.X > _manipStartPoint.X) && ((manipEndPoint.X - _manipStartPoint.X) > threshold))
            {
                LoadPreviousPhoto();
            }
            else if ((manipEndPoint.X < _manipStartPoint.X) && ((_manipStartPoint.X - manipEndPoint.X) > threshold))
            {
                LoadNextPhoto();
            }
        }
```

Let me know if you need any more help.

Thanks,
Kamal.

Comment: thanks for the solution. But can you provide some ways to get swipe effect like the pivot does. Sometimes user just hold and drag it horizontally.